# In angular how to disable or stop the hint | search in datalist

Tags: javascript, angular, search, datalist, hint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4hrK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKptq.png)

in first image you can see only one name is coming but in other image api response showing total 5 records.
so i have to show that all 5 records in that datalist.

Note: if I type any other letters that according API is send the response so i need to show all the object in datalist.

Comment: Can you post the template code responsible for displaying the list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <input type="text" list="testListview"  id="testName{{i}}"
 autocomplete="off"
(keyup)="suggest(lab.get('testName').value,'keyup',lab,$event)"
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z. ,[]-@#]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g,'$1').trimLeft();"
(change)="codeOnChange(lab.get('testName').value,lab,i)"
formControlName="testName"
[datoAutoFocus]=true >
<datalist id="testListview">
<option *ngFor="let test of testList" title="{{test?.name}}">
{{test?.name}}
</option>
</datalist>

Comment: for JSON Data I shared One link so plz check on this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1My6sE_XkcZKTkT6PGW1n22QYxLwsVbRY/view?usp=sharing